# Viewing several attribute tables at the same time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I want to view the attribute tables of several layers at the same time. As far as I know it is only possible to open several attribute tables as tabs, but I want to compare the data of different attribute tables.

Comment: You could join them via a common ID, or intersect the layers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course. In order to just compare them visually it is no problem having several attribute tables open if they are not docked / tabbed:

[image]

If you prefer docked attribute tables just drag and drop them side by side in the blue area:

[image]